# Alternative to PhoneGap builder?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I've been using PhoneGap's Build to assemble my app but recently realized they cap the compressed app size at 9.5 mb. This has put my project on hold until I figure out my next approach as the final size is now 20+ mb.

In the interest of saving time - how can I quickly get this app created with the ease of PhoneGap Build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout [Telerik AppBuilder](http://www.icenium.com/). Its built using Cordova so all your Cordova APIs will work and plugins like Child Browser Barcode Scanner SQLite too..

Answer (score 0):

It's a an old question, but it worth to add another answer just for whom reaching to this page from search engines.

Telerik AppBuilder/Platform is indeed an alternative but:

1. It's not free, in fact it's relatively costly.
2. You might find it useful if you are a beginner in developing Cordova apps and surely pluralsight's tutorial about it will give you a quick start.
3. When you are good in these type of apps and you start having more advanced plugins than the basic one, I'm afraid you will start facing problem with Telerik build and their support is not good on this matter.

So my advice is, if you wish to start with it, do it in a way that you can leave it with minimum pain.

Now a day, after more than 2 years developing Cordova apps, I've ended to use Intel XDK. It's nice, handy and also free.

Comment: "...Intel XDK has been discontinued..." source: INTEL... What a pity

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding to this as I've been asked this question several times lately.  As of this writing, Phonegap Build appears to be on life support.  Their current CLI version is 8.1.1 which is 9 months behind the current CLI.  PGB no longer answers questions in their forums (although just today I did see one staff member answer a question about upgrading to a paid plan... funny since there were 100 questions before that with no answers including one asking if phonegap build was dead.

Intel XDK was indeed the goto for those of us who wanted a good build but they discontinued cordova builds to pursue iOT.  I would have paid double what I pay adobe as their support was stellar and Adobe is adobe.

You can still download Visual Studio with cordova CLI. I've tried it twice and found it buggy as hell... devoured one of my projects on import (thankfully I had it backed up).

You can use MacInCloud.com for iOS builds and deployment to the app store.  They're expensive but if it's your only alternative then I would suggest building locally for android and when you've got it fully working, then use MacInCloud for the iOS builds and deployment to the app store.

For most people, I think a Mac is the only real alternative as you can build all platforms from the Mac.  However it's a huge learning curve to get it configured and working.